# Java 14 VerifyError from innocuous statement

Tags: java, switch-statement, verifyerror, java-14

When attempting to run the following code segment (after successfully compiling it) from eclipse 2020-06 (using jdk-14.0.1):

```
import java.util.*;
public class VerifyErrorTesting {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ArrayList<Double>().add(
            switch("t") {
            case "t" -> Double.valueOf(0);
            default -> 1d;
            }
        );
    }
}
```

I get the following `VerifyError`:

```
Error: Unable to initialize main class othergoofs.VerifyErrorTesting in module goofer
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Instruction type does not match stack map
Exception Details:
  Location:
    othergoofs/VerifyErrorTesting.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V @58: invokevirtual
  Reason:
    Current frame's stack size doesn't match stackmap.
  Current Frame:
    bci: @58
    flags: { }
    locals: { '[Ljava/lang/String;', 'java/lang/String' }
    stack: { 'java/util/ArrayList', 'java/lang/Double' }
  Stackmap Frame:
    bci: @58
    flags: { }
    locals: { '[Ljava/lang/String;' }
    stack: { 'java/util/ArrayList', double, double_2nd }
  Bytecode:
    0000000: bb00 1059 b700 1212 1359 4cb6 0015 ab00
    0000010: 0000 0028 0000 0001 0000 0074 0000 0012
    0000020: 2b12 13b6 001b 9a00 06a7 000d 0eb8 001f
    0000030: b600 25a7 0007 0fb8 001f b600 2957 b1  
  Stackmap Table:
    full_frame(@32,{Object[#47],Object[#22]},{Object[#16]})
    same_locals_1_stack_item_frame(@44,Object[#16])
    same_locals_1_stack_item_frame(@54,Object[#16])
    full_frame(@58,{Object[#47]},{Object[#16],Double})
```

I have tried compiling the same code with javac and it runs without issue; the error only occurs when running from eclipse. When I change the code even slightly, the error goes away. For example, changing `Double.valueOf(0)` to `0d` runs without error. Changing `1d` to `Double.valueOf(1)` also runs without error. Replacing `new ArrayList<Double>().add` with `Double d=` or `double d=` runs fine as well.

My question is: What is causing the `VerifyError`?

Comment: Probably: the eclipse compiler creating invalid byte code. I think this rather asks for a defect on the eclipse compiler issue tracker.

Comment: The switch must balance the types Double and double to a same type. Expected is Double, but that does not seem to come into play. You could check the (un-)boxing done within the byte code.