# java.lang.verify error : Inconsistent stack height 1 != 2

Tags: java, bytecode, instruction-set, bytecode-manipulation, javap

I have a custom application in which we have generated the Java Instruction code.We are generating the code using **javacc**. In one of the Scenarios, we are getting **java.lang.verify error : Inconsistent stack height 1 != 2**

I checked the generated class file as well as tried to decode the instruction set, but couldn't understand why i am getting this error.
**class: Test, method: runFunc signature: ()Ljava/lang/Object;) Inconsistent stack height 1 != 2**

with detailed exception as

*java.lang.VerifyError: (class: Test, method: runFunc signature: ()Ljava/lang/Object;) Inconsistent stack height 1 != 2

```
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2178)
```

I checked the generated class code and the runFunc Function is as shown below:

```
protected final Object runFunc() {
        out = ((myPage) this).pageContext.getOut();
        parent = ((myPage) this).parent;
        ((myPage) this).pageContext.setPageEncoding("test");

        this.__tempIntertnalARRYSTRUCTVAR0.set(currentPage.StructNew());
        __myapp_internal_sdref_ = Cast._Map(_autoscalarize(this.__tempIntertnalARRYSTRUCTVAR0));
        __myapp_internal_sdref___restkeys = new ArrayList(4);
        _setDref_Struct(null, __myapp_internal_sdref_, "a", false);
        _set("rest", myPage._dreference_map_rest(__myapp_internal_sdref_, __myapp_internal_sdref___restkeys));

        outVar = (printOutput) _initFunction(class$myApplication$ext$io$printOutput, 0, parent);
        _setCurrentLineNo(41);
        outVar.hasEndAttribute(true);

        try {
            if ((mode0 = outVar.doStart()) != 0)
                do {

                } while (outVar.doAfterBody() != 0);
            if (outVar.doEnd() == 5) {
                t8 = null;
                outVar.doFinally();
                return t8;
            }
            outVar.doFinally();
        } catch (Throwable throwable) {
            outVar.doCatch(throwable);
            outVar.doFinally();
        } catch (Throwable throwable) {
            outVar.doFinally();
            throw throwable;
        }
        _whitespace((Writer) out, "\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n");
        return null;
    }
```

While the generated Instruction code for the same function obtained using javap utility looks as follows:

```
protected final java.lang.Object runFunc();
    Code:
    0:aload_0
    1:getfield      #40                 // Field myApplication/runtime/myPage.pageContext:LmyApplication/runtime/AppPageContext;
    4:invokevirtual #46                 // Method javax/servlet/jsp/JspContext.getOut:()Ljavax/servlet/jsp/JspWriter;
    7:astore_1
    8:aload_0
    9:getfield      #50                 // Field myApplication/runtime/myPage.parent:Ljavax/servlet/jsp/ext/Operation;
    12:astore_3
    13:aload_0
    14:getfield      #40                 // Field myApplication/runtime/myPage.pageContext:LmyApplication/runtime/AppPageContext;
    17:ldc           #52                 // String test
    19:invokevirtual #58                 // Method myApplication/runtime/AppPageContext.setPageEncoding:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    22:aload_0
    23:getfield      #33                 // Field __tempIntertnalARRYSTRUCTVAR0:LmyApplication/runtime/Variable;
    26:invokestatic  #62                 // Method myApplication/runtime/currentPage.StructNew:()Ljava/util/Map;
    29:invokevirtual #68                 // Method myApplication/runtime/Variable.set:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    32:aload_0
    33:aload_0
    34:getfield      #33                 // Field __tempIntertnalARRYSTRUCTVAR0:LmyApplication/runtime/Variable;
    37:invokevirtual #72                 // Method myApplication/runtime/myPage._autoscalarize:(myApplication/runtime/Variable;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    40:invokestatic  #78                 // Method myApplication/runtime/Cast._Map:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/util/Map;
    43:astore 4
    45:new           #80                 // class java/util/ArrayList
    48:dup
    49:iconst_4
    50:invokespecial #83                 // Method java/util/ArrayList."<init>":(I)V
    53:astore 5
    55:aload_0
    56:aconst_null
    57:aload 4
    59:ldc           #85                 // String a
    61:iconst_0
    62:invokevirtual #89                 // Method myApplication/runtime/myPage._setDref_Struct:(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Map;Ljava/lang/Object;Z)V
    65:aload 5
    67:ldc           #85                 // String a
    69:invokeinterface #95,2           // InterfaceMethod java/util/List.add:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
    74:aload_0
    75:ldc           #97                 // String rest
    77:aload 4
    79:aload 5
    81:invokestatic  #101                // Method myApplication/runtime/myPage._dreference_map_rest:(Ljava/util/Map;Ljava/util/List;)Ljava/util/Map;
    84:invokevirtual #105                // Method myApplication/runtime/myPage._set:(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    87:aload_0
    88:getstatic     #117                // Field class$myApplication$ext$io$printOutput:Ljava/lang/Class;
    91:iconst_0
    92:aload_3
    93:invokevirtual #121                // Method myApplication/runtime/myPage._initFunction:(Ljava/lang/Class;ILjavax/servlet/jsp/ext/Operation;)Ljavax/servlet/jsp/ext/Operation;
    96:checkcast     #123                // class myApplication/ext/io/printOutput
    99:astore 6
    101:aload_0
    102:bipush 41
    104:invokevirtual #126                // Method myApplication/runtime/myPage._setCurrentLineNo:(I)V
    107:aload 6
    109:iconst_1
    110:invokevirtual #132                // Method myApplication/ext/GenericOperation.hasEndAttribute:(Z)V
    113:aload 6
    115:invokevirtual #136                // Method myApplication/ext/io/printOutput.doStart:()I
    118:dup
    119:istore 7
    121:ifeq 132
    124:aload 6
    126:invokevirtual #139                // Method myApplication/ext/io/printOutput.doAfterBody:()I
    129:ifne 124
    132:aload 6
    134:invokevirtual #144                // Method myApplication/ext/QueryLoop.doEnd:()I
    137:iconst_5
    138:if_icmpne 150
    141:aconst_null
    142:astore 8
    144:jsr 179
    147:aload 8
    149:areturn
    150:jsr 179
    153:goto 188
    156:astore 9
    158:aload 6
    160:aload 9
    162:invokevirtual #148                // Method myApplication/ext/QueryLoop.doCatch:(Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
    165:jsr 179
    168:goto 188
    171:astore 10
    173:jsr 179
    176:aload 10
    178:athrow
    179:astore 11
    181:aload 6
    183:invokevirtual #151                // Method myApplication/ext/io/printOutput.doFinally:()V
    186:ret 11
    188:aload_0
    189:aload_1
    190:ldc           #153                // String \r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n
    192:invokevirtual #157                // Method myApplication/runtime/myPage._whitespace:(Ljava/io/Writer;Ljava/lang/String;)V
    195:aconst_null
    196:areturn
```

I would really appreciate if some-one can point me out as to where does the stack im balancing happens?
Anticipating positive response,
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Try a newer JDK. They might provide more information in the exception message.

Comment: Thanks @Holger for the response, i tried using Java 15 and the error remains the same. The exception is as shown below:

java.lang.VerifyError: (class: Test, method: runFunc signature: ()Ljava/lang/Object;) Inconsistent stack height 1 != 2
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:3296)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3501)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2711)

Comment: That’s strange as in recent JDKs, those errors look like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63779210/2711488), providing information about the problematic location and some more…

Comment: There is a mismatch between the two codes. Between the `_setDref_Struct` and the `_dreference_map_rest` method invocations, the bytecode contains the instructions for `__myapp_internal_sdref___restkeys .add("a")` that does not appear in the other code. This invocation also seems to be the problem, as it produces a `boolean` result value that is never popped from the operand stack. I might be wrong though, analyzing such things from textual dumps instead of applying dedicated tools to the actual code, is error prone.

Comment: @Holger, I guess that is correct, even i realized, when i was doing individual instruction set mapping that we are doing too many load calls without using store call in
the above instruction set from #65 to #84 line and that boolean returned value is an error for sure. Thanks a lot for your help, i really appreciate it.